# What does "#APP" in the assembly file generated by compiler mean?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, directive, inline-assembly

I wrote the following code:

```
// a.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

_Noreturn void _start()
{
    register int syscall_num asm ("rax") = __NR_exit;
    register int exit_code   asm ("rdi") = 0;

    // The actual syscall to exit
    asm volatile ("syscall"
        : /* no output Operands */
        : "r" (syscall_num), "r" (exit_code));
}
```

And then compiled it using `clang-7 -Oz -pipe -flto -c a.c` and used `llc-7 -filetype=asm a.o` to turn it into an human-readable assembly file `a.o.s`:

```
    .text
    .file   "a.c"
    .globl  _start                  # -- Begin function _start
    .type   _start,@function
_start:                                 # @_start
    .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:
    pushq   $60
    .cfi_adjust_cfa_offset 8
    popq    %rax
    .cfi_adjust_cfa_offset -8
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    #APP
    syscall
    #NO_APP
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _start, .Lfunc_end0-_start
    .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function

    .ident  "clang version 7.0.1-svn348686-1~exp1~20181211133235.57 (branches/release_70)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

In the assembly above, the directive `#APP` appears before `syscall`, which is the assembly I wrote and the directive `#NO_APP` appears right after it.

I know it must have something to do with the use of `asm`, like to prevent it from being optimized out, but I can't find any documentation of it after googling.

Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically at least, the compiler told `as`  it could use a fast-parsing mode for parsing pure compiler output, switching back for full parsing for blocks from inline-asm.  There should be a `#APP` somewhere early in the file that enters this mode.  The `#NO_APP` switches out of this mode.

I'm not sure `as` does anything with that hint anymore, so it may not even look for `#NO_APP` at all, and just treat it like any other comment.

**In practice, it delimits the block of text that came from the inline asm template, vs. compiler generated asm**.  It doesn't do anything beyond that, and if you're hand-editing the asm for some reason, it's totally find to remove it.

Comment: Are you sure the fast parser is gone?  I believe it still exists, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @fuz: I'm not *sure*, but I think I read that a while ago.  I just tried assembling a hand-written file that started with `#APP`, and comments and a `.equ` definition worked fine inside it.  I didn't try a `.macro`.

Answer (score 2):

Those macros disable (`#NO_APP`) or enable (`#APP`) the preprocessor, allowing for faster parsing by disabling the preprocessor when it is not needed.

From the gas manual,

> If the first line of an input file is '#NO_APP' or if you use the
> '-f' option, whitespace and comments are not removed from the input
> file.  Within an input file, you can ask for whitespace and comment
> removal in specific portions of the by putting a line that says '#APP'
> before the text that may contain whitespace or comments, and putting a
> line that says '#NO_APP' after this text.  This feature is mainly intend
> to support 'asm' statements in compilers whose output is otherwise free
> of comments and whitespace.

You can find this warning in the section about the `-f` option:

> *Warning:* if you use '-f' when the files actually need to be
> preprocessed (if they contain comments, for example), 'as' does not
> work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It removes the whitespace and the comments  between it and #NO_APP.

In this case it was placed here just in case as you have the comment in your asm()